Solr sorting : multiply the bf score with a field
I have docs in my index, where every doc has a field popularity, which is a float.
What I want: multiply the field popularity by the score value (computed using bf) and order the docs by popularity * score desc.
what I tried: "sort":"mul(score, popularity) desc", which gives me the error "Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec 'mul(score, popularity_v2.fr) desc', pos=10"
Thanks for your help!

Wouldn't the boost parameter achieve that without explicitly sorting by it? i.e. boost=popularity?

Yes, this works, thank you !
